# Iterate JSON Objects from ODATA feed and download content from each into Blob using Azure Data Factory or Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory, power-automate

I've been struggling with this for a few days. I have an odata feed with 100+ objects. I want to get a list of all of the objects and build a query for each one that pulls the data from each and creates a file in blob storage with the content of each file. Surely someone has done this before and can help.

I'm open to using Azure Data Factory or Azure Logic. This is a sample payload from the odata feed metadata.

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://somewebsite/Apps/WebServices/OData.svc/$metadata",
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "Table1",
      "url": "Table1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Table2",
      "url": "Table2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Table3",
      "url": "Table3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: 100 isn't that much and if that's going to be a consistent amount, I'd go with Logic Apps which has a lot more flexibility and options.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve your goal using Azure Data Factory.

You can get a list of all the objects in odata using [lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity), then link a  [foreach activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) after the lookup activity, with a copy activity in the foreach activity.